# Weights Update - Ensemble Models

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, posterior, anomaly-detection, ensemble-learning

I must identify if a data point is an outlier or not in a dataset (we don't have labels). I have different unsupervised models to identify the outlier. Then, I normalize the outlier score and I combine them via a weight average. According to the fact that I don't have information about their accuracy I use the same weight for each models.

Now, suppose that I have a small fraction of the dataset with also the label.

How can I update the weights according to the new information?

This is what I think that could work, but I don't have reference to say that for sure.

Imagine that I have 4 models. The probability of the model I assume that is the weight, so 0.25.

$$ P(Model) = 0.25  $$

Then, the likelihood:

$$ P(Outlier | Model) $$

that are the normalized outlier score.

And so, the posterior is:

$$ P(Model | Outlier) = P(Outlier | Model) P(Model)$$

My question is: can I sum all the different posterior probability for each observation and then normalize w.r.t. the sum of the other models?

I give you an example in python of my thinking:

````
import numpy as np

def bayesian_update(anomaly, weight, prob):
    #inizialization vector
    posterior = np.zeros(len(anomaly))
    
    
    for i in range(len(anomaly)):
        #if the labled indicate an anomaly
        if anomaly[i] == 1:
            posterior[i] = prob[i] * weight
        #if the labled indicate a non anomaly
        else:
            posterior[i] = (1-prob[i]) * weight
    return posterior



np.random.seed(0)
n_observations = 100
n_models = 4

# 
models_probs = np.random.rand(n_observations, n_models)


#a way to indicate that the first model (colomn) is better
anomaly = np.where(models_probs[:, 0] > 0.5, 1, 0)

posterior_sum = np.zeros(n_models)

for i in range(n_models):
    posterior_sum[i] = np.sum(bayesian_update(anomaly, 0.25, models_probs[:, i]))
    
new_weight = posterior_sum/np.sum(posterior_sum)

print(new_weight)



```
````

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a stacking approach where you build a meta predictor using the 4 model outputs as features? In your case I would consider building a Naïve Bayes classifier and then predicting an outlier based on the maximum a-posteriori hypothesis:
\begin{align}
P(Outlier|m_1,...,m_4) &\propto P(Outlier) \prod_{m=1}^4 P(M_i=m_i|Outlier) \\
P(\neg Outlier|m_1,...,m_4) &\propto P(\neg Outlier) \prod_{m=1}^4 P(M_i=m_i|\neg Outlier)
\end{align}
where $m_i$ is the output of the $i$-th unsupervised outlier detection model for a given new point. You predict "Outlier" whenever $P(Outlier|m_1,...,m_4) > P(\neg Outlier|m_1,...,m_4)$.
From your labelled training set (assumed to be representative) you need to:

- estimate the prior probabilities $P(Outlier)$ and $P(\neg Outlier)$
- estimate $P(M_i=1|Outlier)$ which is the sensitivity (true positive rate) of predictor $i$ (and hence also find $P(M_i=0|Outlier)=1-P(M_i=1|Outlier)$)
- estimate $P(M_i=0|\neg Outlier)$ which is the specificity (true negative rate) of predictor $i$ (and hence also find $P(M_i=1|\neg Outlier)=1-P(M_i=0|\neg Outlier)$).

So, for example, if the 4 predictors predict [0,1,0,1], you would predict "outlier" if:
$$P(Outlier) \cdot (1-Sens_1) \cdot Sens_2 \cdot (1-Sens_3) \cdot Sens_4
>
P(\neg Outlier) \cdot Spec_1 \cdot (1-Spec_2) \cdot Spec_3 \cdot (1-Spec_4).
$$

As you can see, compared to a simple model average, this approach takes into account the breakdown in terms of sensitivity and specificity rather than just the model's accuracy.

---

If your models $m_i$ provide a score, rather than a binary value, you can use pretty much the same approach by changing the conditional probabilities into $P(M_i\ge m_i|Outlier)$ (etc), which can be estimated by counting how many of the "Outlier" examples in the labelled training set provided a score at least as high as the current sample (and same for the "$\neg$Outliers").

Comment: Thank you very much Luca for reply me! Actually, I was thinking to use this paper "Converting Output Scores from Outlier Detection Algorithms into Probability Estimates" (the part about the mixture of normal and exponential) to convert the outlier score into probability for each models. So I should have the P(Outlier | outlier score) for each outlier score and models (in the paper should be t_i). But they use a way to ensemble the model that not convince me. So, I thought to use a weighted average.

Comment: I was considering to use a stacking approach, but I don't know how. Maybe I could use your last suggestion to update the information. Also because the mixture method give you the alpha that it is the P(outlier) or not. But I would not give so importance to the small dataset with the labels, I'm not sure that It will be representative. For the first part I'm confused about what is P(Mi=mi|Outlier). I mean I don't know If one observation is an outlier or not.